# How to use OnItemClickListener in Navigation Drawer?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I have a `Navigation Drawer` in my App.I have the items in the drawer but I don't know how I can open new Activity from each of items .

I have Tried some Methods & Commented It ...

Thanks for your Help ...

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    protected DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private CustomActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String[] menuItems;
    String LOG_TAG = "Remote It";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        supportRequestWindowFeature(WindowCompat.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        // getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_drawer);

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        _initMenu();
        mDrawerToggle = new CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer);
        mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        // if (savedInstanceState == null)
        // {
        // selectItem(0);
        // }

    }

    private void _initMenu()
    {
        NsMenuAdapter mAdapter = new NsMenuAdapter(this);

        // Add Header
        mAdapter.addHeader(R.string.ns_menu_main_header);

        // Add first block

        menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ns_menu_items);
        String[] menuItemsIcon = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ns_menu_items_icon);

        int res = 0;
        for (String item : menuItems)
        {

            int id_title = getResources().getIdentifier(item, "string", this.getPackageName());
            int id_icon = getResources().getIdentifier(menuItemsIcon[res], "drawable", this.getPackageName());

            NsMenuItemModel mItem = new NsMenuItemModel(id_title, id_icon);
            // if (res==1) mItem.counter=12; //it is just an example...
            // if (res==3) mItem.counter=3; //it is just an example...
            mAdapter.addItem(mItem);
            res++;
        }

        mAdapter.addHeader(R.string.ns_menu_main_header2);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        if (mDrawerList != null)
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.control_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content
        // view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_keyboard).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        /*
         * The action bar home/up should open or close the drawer.
         * ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
         */
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        {
            return true;
        }

        // Handle your other action bar items...
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class CustomActionBarDrawerToggle extends ActionBarDrawerToggle
    {

        public CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity mActivity, DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout)
        {
            super(mActivity, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.ns_menu_open, R.string.ns_menu_close);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
        {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.ns_menu_close));
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
        {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.ns_menu_open));
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    }

    //private void selectItem(int position)
    //{
    //  switch (position)
    //  {
    //      case 1:
    //          Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ControlActivity.class);
    //          startActivity(a);
    //          break;
    //      case 2:
    //          Intent b = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tutorial.class);
    //          startActivity(b);
    //          break;
    //      default:
    //  }
    //}

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the
            // drawer
            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            //mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            // String text = "menu click... should be implemented";
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text,
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // // You should reset item counter
            //mDrawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tutorial.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }

}
```

**NOTE**
I need it to work with activities & not with Fragments .

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `NavigationDrawer` in all your activities you can launch from the NavigationDrawer, the best way to handle that is not to launch new `Activity`, but to replace `Fragment`.

Because if you launch a new `Activity` each time you'll need to implement your `NavigationDrawer` in all your subactivities. (easily doable with heritage though).

There is a nice tutorial here to play with "replace" Fragments with the `NavigationDrawer` :

http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/

Comment: Well, you can... Do a "generic" Activity with the NavigationDrawer, and make all of your Activity inherit from it. And you'll have your NavigationDrawer everywhere. Don't forget to "finish()" your activity when you launch another one though.

Comment: I think you have to read the Question again.I have my Drawer Perfect in all Activities.Now i want to Link the items in the Drawer to open other activities when an Item is pressed.

Comment: And a startActivity() doesn't work ? Is your onItemClick() method called ?

Comment: It is Called & the startActivity Works.But i need to call Activity according to the Item Clicked ...

Comment: You have the position of the item clicked, what do you want more ?